# Are there parasitoids of mosquitoes ? (other than nematodes)

Tags: entomology, ecology, parasitism, mosquitoes

Outside of nematodes, are there any examples of organisms that are parasitoids of mosquitoes ?

I could not find any example in literature so far. I'm notably interested to know if the most known mosquito genera (*Aedes*, *Anopheles*, *Culex*...) have already been described to be parasitized by other insects (e. g. parasitoid wasps), and if this is a common phenomenon in nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens I just found an answer to my question in a recent review book by George Heimpel and Nicolas Mills. It appears that for now we do not know any  parasitoid of mosquitoes.

Quoting chapter 1 :

> "Most insect herbivore species are attacked by
>   one or more parasitoid species, but some major
>   arthropod pest groups appear to be entirely free
>   of parasitoid attack. For instance, we know of no
>   parasitoids that attack mosquitoes or other biting
>   flies with aquatic larval stages, and no parasitoids
>   that attack phytophagous mites or adelgids."

**Source:**
Heimpel, G., & Mills, N. (2017). Definitions and Interactions. In Biological Control: Ecology and Applications (pp. 1-18). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/9781139029117.003